# Last value not showing in bar graph of charts.js-library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chart.js

I created a bar graph, but I only see 5 values from the 6 labels that I created. Even on the [charts.js website](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-introduction), the bar graph example they used only shows 6 values out of the 7 created labels.

**My code**

```
'use strict'

$(function () {
var data = {
  labels: ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Java", "Wordpress", "Boostrap"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My Skill Set",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [100, 90, 80, 82, 85, 88],
        }
    ]
};
var options = {};
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data,
    options: options
  });
});
```

Comment: I know why `July` isn't showing anything in the reference you provided.. it's because the y-axis doesn't start at 0.. it starts at 40... but at the same time 40 is the lowest value in the reference you provided.. but 88 is not the smallest value in your `data` array.. can you post a picture of your graph?

Comment: You are right in terms of the scale. My graph starts as 80 as it is the lowest value. How exactly do you change the scale?

Comment: Was my answer able to help you?

Comment: Your first comment guided me on the right track. I went ahead and came up with the answer below, which is similar to yours. I selected your answer as the best answer, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found this from the reference you provided..

```
ar myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'bar',
data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

try that out.

Answer (score 7):

I actually came up with this:

```
var options = {
  scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            display: true,
            ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,    // minimum will be 0, unless there is a lower value.
                // OR //
                beginAtZero: true   // minimum value will be 0.
            }
        }]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will set offset:true in y axis then it will show all values in bar chart. It can be done like this:

```
 scales: {
    ...this.options.scales,
    yAxes: [{
      offset: true,
      ticks: {
        callback: this.getValueWith(unit),
      },
    }],
    xAxes: [{
      offset: !this.isLine(),
      ticks: {
        callback: this.getLabel(),
      },
    }],
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add extra step to min and max tick steps of each axis.

```js
options: {
  scales: {
    y: {
      beginAtZero: false, //at yourchoice
      grace: 1
    }
  }
}
```